# setup Azure Redis Cache as LRU

Tags: caching, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

Using the preview of [Azure redis cache](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/), and it's working great. But I can't figure out how to configure it as LRU cache, as described by the redis docs.
The exception is

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: ERR unknown command 'CONFIG'

My code was

```
server.ConfigSet("maxmemory", "250m");
server.ConfigSet("maxmemory-policy", "allkeys-lru");
```

Comment: Just to explain: the error is because the command has been disabled (or renamed to something that only the azure host knows the name of). StackExchange.Redis supports command renaming, but it seems unlikely that you'd know the name of the config command on a cloud-hosted node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config has been currently been disabled for the initial Azure Redis Cache (Preview).
We will be selectively be opening this up as we refresh the Preview.

By default the maxmemory-policy is set to volatile-lru.

Update - Max Memory Policy is now configurable via the Cache blade.

Comment: awesome! thanks for confirming. glad to hear that it's setup by default as LRU cache.